# How do i debug database related error in Agiletookit ? ATK4

Tags: php, mysql, atk4, agiletoolkit

I know about the $m->debug(); as mentioned [here](http://agiletoolkit.org/learn/understand/model/debug)

But i am not sure how i should start debugging the following issue. My approach will be doing a var_dump inside dsql.php and compare fields and then go step by step upwards in the OOP layers. I was wondering if there was some easy way to do the same thing.

### Actual Error:

```
/Users/Qambar/Work/VERYCOOLAWESOMEPROJECT/atk4/lib/DB/dsql.php  :1518   bozims_db_db_dsql_mysql DB_dsql_mysql-  >exception("Database Query Failed")
```

### Full Log

```
/Users/Qambar/Work/VERYCOOLAWESOMEPROJECT/atk4/lib/BaseException.php    :63     Exception_DB    Exception_DB->collectBasicData(Null)
/Users/Qambar/Work/VERYCOOLAWESOMEPROJECT/atk4/lib/AbstractObject.php   :545    Exception_DB    Exception_DB->__construct("Database Query Failed", Null)
/Users/Qambar/Work/VERYCOOLAWESOMEPROJECT/atk4/lib/DB/dsql.php  :1518   bozims_db_db_dsql_mysql DB_dsql_mysql->exception("Database Query Failed")
/Users/Qambar/Work/VERYCOOLAWESOMEPROJECT/atk4/lib/DB/dsql.php  :1545   bozims_db_db_dsql_mysql DB_dsql_mysql->execute()
/Users/Qambar/Work/VERYCOOLAWESOMEPROJECT/atk4/lib/SQL/Model.php    :635    bozims_db_db_dsql_mysql DB_dsql_mysql->insert()
/Users/Qambar/Work/VERYCOOLAWESOMEPROJECT/atk4/lib/SQL/Model.php    :610    bozims_fileadmin_form_Upload_test_filestore_model_file  filestore\Model_File->insert()
/Users/Qambar/Work/VERYCOOLAWESOMEPROJECT/atk4/lib/Form/Field/Upload.php    :143    bozims_fileadmin_form_Upload_test_filestore_model_file  filestore\Model_File->save()
/   :   bozims_fileadmin_form_Upload_test   Form_Field_Upload->loadPOST(Object(Form))
/Users/Qambar/Work/VERYCOOLAWESOMEPROJECT/atk4/lib/AbstractObject.php   :786        Loggercall_user_func_array(Array(2), Array(1))
/Users/Qambar/Work/VERYCOOLAWESOMEPROJECT/atk4/lib/Form/Basic.php   :348    bozims_fileadmin_form   Form->hook("loadPOST")
/   :   bozims_fileadmin_form   Form->submitted(Object(Frontend))
/Users/Qambar/Work/VERYCOOLAWESOMEPROJECT/atk4/lib/AbstractObject.php   :786        Loggercall_user_func_array(Array(2), Array(1))
/Users/Qambar/Work/VERYCOOLAWESOMEPROJECT/atk4/lib/ApiWeb.php   :290    bozims  Frontend->hook("submitted")
/Users/Qambar/Work/VERYCOOLAWESOMEPROJECT/index.php :5  bozims  Frontend->main()
```

Comment: It also gave me following text in the error message.

query: insert into `filestore_file` (`filestore_type_id`,`filestore_volume_id`,`original_filename`,`filename`,`filesize`,`deleted`) values (:a,:a_2,:a_3,:a_4,:a_5,:a_6)
template: insert [options_insert] into [table_noalias] ([set_fields]) values ([set_values])
upload_error: File was uploaded properly

Comment: i also tried changing the table from innodb to myisam it didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually - do a debug() which will give you a query itself. Copy-paste query into SQL console. If you get error there, then try to understand why.

You can also use setActualFields to narrow down list of fields queried, which will make your query simpler.

That should help you narrow down the problem.